# How can I use LINQ to avoid calling Contains() inside a Where() clause?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a LINQ expression that's pretty straightforward:

```
class Foo
{
   ...
   int Id { get; }
}

IEnumerable<Foo> foos = ...;
IEnumerable<int> ids = ...;

var remainder = foos.Where(f => !ids.Contains(f.Id));
```

I'm thinking that there might be a way to produce the same `remainder` set using `Join()` and/or `Intersection()` and/or `Except()`, but I'm not clever enough to formulate it.

I'm struggling with the `!` in the Join(), because projected-set *intersection* in terms of `Join()` is:

```
var intersection = foos.Join(ids, f => f.Id, i => i, (f, id) => f);
```

but I'm looking for the inverse. Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with `Contains`? If you worry about performance in a large list, use `HashSet` instead of the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: There's no *problem*, specifically. I'm looking to understand LINQ in a deeper way.

Comment: use [Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) vs `Contains`

Comment: Then ask a specific problem which is not understood. You can prepare a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: `Contain` is converted to `IN` in SQL, however `Any()` is converted to`Exist` and there are difference in performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeking for in the [Relational algrebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) is called **Antijoin**. In relational database it's implemented usually with `left outer join` (or *left **semijoin*** if we use the same terminology) with checking `right` side for `NULL`. The closest LINQ construct is the [GroupJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) with check for empty inner group.

Here is how it will look for your sample (compare it to `Contains` based version)

*Query syntax:*

```
var remainder = from foo in foos
        join id in ids on foo.Id equals id into idGroup
        where !idGroup.Any()
        select foo;
```

*Method syntax:*

```
var remainder = foos.GroupJoin(ids, foo => foo.Id, id => id, (foo, idGroup) => new { foo, idGroup })
    .Where(e => !e.idGroup.Any())
    .Select(e => e.foo);
```