# compare nested json collections using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to compare nested json collections against one another using C# linq. Here is an example of the json collections
and the classes that they get bound to.

=== collection 1 ===

```
[
    {
        "contractId": "100-200-A",
        "invoices": [
            {
                invoiceNumber: 987654
            },
            {
                invoiceNumber: 555999
            }           
        ]
    },
    {
        "contractId": "300-777-Z",
        "invoices": [
            {
                invoiceNumber: 12345
            },
            {
                invoiceNumber: 100025
            }           
        ]
    }
]

public class Contract
{
    public string ContractId { get; set; }
    public IList<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    public class Invoice 
    {
        public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

=== collection 2 ===

```
[
    {
        "paymentDate": "01/01/2000",
        "contracts":[
            {
                "contractId": "100-200-A",
                "invoices": [
                    {
                        invoiceNumber: 987654
                    },
                    {
                        invoiceNumber: 555999
                    },
                    {
                        invoiceNumber: 444333
                    },
                    {
                        invoiceNumber: 111000
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "contractId": "300-777-Z",
                "invoices": [
                    {
                        invoiceNumber: 12345
                    },
                    {
                        invoiceNumber: 100025
                    },
                    {
                        invoiceNumber: 888666
                    },
                    {
                        invoiceNumber: 222999
                    }                   
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

public class PaymentRequest
{
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public IList<ContractList> Contracts { get; set; }
    public class ContractList
    {       
        public string ContractId { get; set; }  
        public IList<InvoiceList> Invoices { get; set; }
    }

    public class InvoiceList
    {          
        public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Assuming that the contractId's are the same in both collections, I can create a linq join between the two, I am having a hard time trying to find the extra invoices that are in the 2nd collection set. Essentially, I need to get back a list of all the invoice numbers for that specific contractId that are in the 2nd collection that are not present in the 1st collection.

Comment: Why do you have two different classes for the same thing? `Invoice` vs `InvoiceList` and `Contract` vs `ContractList`?

Comment: valid question. dealing with existing implementation and a lot of class properties (from both) were left off for brevity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is called *antijoin*. The corresponding LINQ construct is [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) with check for empty inner group. See [How can I use LINQ to avoid calling Contains() inside a Where() clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232348/how-can-i-use-linq-to-avoid-calling-contains-inside-a-where-clause/35233149#35233149)

Applying it to your use case (assuming the same data structure as in your previous questions) could be something like this:

```
var query =
    from request in (
        from contract in paymentRequest.Contracts
        from invoice in contract.Invoices
        select new { contract, invoice }
    )
    join valid in (
         from contract in validContracts
         from invoice in contract.InvoiceList
         select new { contract, invoice }
    )
    on new { request.contract.ContractId, request.invoice.InvoiceNumber }
    equals new { valid.contract.ContractId, valid.invoice.InvoiceNumber }
    into validRequests
    where !validRequests.Any()
    select request;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
foreach (var contract in payment.Contracts)
{
    var otherContract = contracts.First(c => c.ContractId == contract.ContractId);
    var missingInvoiceNumbers = contract.Invoices.Where(i => !otherContract.Invoices.Any(inv => inv.InvoiceNumber == i.InvoiceNumber))
                                                 .Select(i => i.InvoiceNumber);
    // do something with the results, like adding them to a dictionary <contract.ContractId, missingInvoiceNumbers>
}
```

It's not pure LINQ, but better have it readable for future.

Answer (score 0):

> find the extra invoices that are in the 2nd collection set

Let's call list1 and list2 to the contacts lists you need to compare. The linq should be like this:

```
list1.Join(list2, x=>x.ContactId, x=>x.ContactId, 
    (c1,c2)=>new {
        c2.ContactId,
        MissingInv=c2.Invoices.Where(x=>c1.Invoices.All(y=>x!=y))
    });
```